# Определение IPv4 для прокси

Tags: php, vpn, ipv6

помогите правильно определить IPv4 на PHP у человека, который использует прокси.

Есть getenv() он тут [пример](http://www.gcmsite.ru/?pg=art&id=php-people-information) правильно определяет IP (если смотреть через VPN), но при установки его на свой сайт он отображает IPv6- 3001:27c:198c:906:3::29c

Нужно именно получить IPv4 у людей, которые используют VPN

Comment: VPN в принципе никак не показывает реальный IP-адрес пользователя, и узнать его невозможно.

Comment: мне не нужен реальный. На примере из описания при VPN показывает IPv4 - http://joxi.ru/Vm6nRDjCj3xz1m Я никак не могу сделать также (получить IP vpn)

Comment: Если VPN посещает ваш сайт по IPv6, то никакого IPv4 и не будет, всё правильно. Если вы хотите IPv4, значит отключите IPv6 на своём сайте

Comment: Ещё раз для тех кто в танке. Есть сайт http://www.gcmsite.ru/?pg=art&id=php-people-information При посещение его функция getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") отдаёт ipv4 прокси VPN. При посещении моего, этого не происходит

Comment: Ещё раз для тех кто в танке: сайт gcmsite.ru НЕ поддерживает IPv6, и адресу IPv6 там взяться неоткуда. Если вы хотите такое же поведение у себя — отключите поддержу IPv6 на своём сайте.